# UISplitViewController reload data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

How can I call function from UISplitViewController subclass to other ViewController.

I have an application that displays splitview and shows modal popup after. When popup is closed, I need to reload data. So appdelegate looks like this:

```
[self.window addSubview:splitview.view];
[splitview presentModalViewController:popup_ctrl animated:YES];
```

On TableViewController I've made funcion reloadData;

I found out that by subclassing UISplitViewController, I can detect closing of popup with -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated. I've tried following code:

```
[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] reloadData];
```

However it crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector.

What do I have to modify to make the function reloadData work?

Comment: Are you shure that table view is loaded into split view at the time you sending reloadData message?

Comment: I have no idea, atleast viewControllers count == 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not explicitly add a property to your SplitViewController that references your TableViewController?

Then you can say

```
mySplitViewController.TableViewController = myTableViewController;
```

and later call

```
[mySplitViewController.TableViewController reloadData];
```